How do sites like "www.isitdownrightnow.com" determine that a website is operational?
How do "status checker" websites like "isitdownrightnow.com", "Hosting Checker" or "isitup.com" determine that a website is operational?  It's got to be more than a ping?
I'm asking because I'd like to propose a similar function for the internal sites for the company where I work.  The challenge with our network is that most sites are heavily authenticated with various combinations of CAC cards, PIV cards and RSA tokens.  Plus some company sites are actually external sites.

In general it's more interesting to know if a service is functioning than if a particular IP is online, so you should in general make such tests as specific as possible.
For instance, imagine a webserver with a full disk; the login page loads fine, but login fails because /tmp is full, and session files can't be written to disk. The service is down, but a test will not discover this unless it verifies it's able to log in.
It may also be useful to monitor indirect parameters, such as database transaction times; if these rise the application may be impacted.
Monitoring complex services is complex, and is often a combination of testing endpoints, watching logs and monitoring the host.
Sites such as the one mentioned tend to have functional tests implemented for big sites such as facebook and twitter, while for smaller sites they just do a HTTP(S) request, and if it responds with 200 it's happy.

Sounds like the server / application being polled needs to support a "how are you feeling today?" service call.  Making it unauthenticated would make it easier on the polling service but would not be acceptable to cybersecurity group.    Hmmmm.  I wonder if request to the server/app login page could return some health info headers or the login page contained a hidden DIV with health info.

It's more than a ping usually as multiple site can be hosted on one public IP. They analyse the site answer header usually to be sure that the site answer something good.
A Ok request (200) vs a server error 500 will have different meaning in a report.
